# Uma chave estrangeira pode referenciar mais de uma tabela?

Tags: banco-de-dados

gostaria de saber se é possível uma chave estrangeira referenciar mais de uma tabela, por exemplo:

tabela cliente
PK - código cliente
- nome cliente

tabela funcionario
PK - código funcionário
- nome funcionário

tabela contato
- telefone
- e-mail
FK - código contato, referência tabela cliente(código cliente), referência tabela funcionário (código funcionário)

Comment: Não vejo sentido em tal tipo de relacionamento. Talvez você deva considerar as tabelas cliente e funcionário como particionamentos de uma única tabela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma chave estrangeira não pode referenciar mais de uma tabela; na verdade, isso iria contra os princípios da própria modelagem lógica de dados.

A maneira mais correta de se relacionar as tabelas no exemplo mencionado seria:

Tabela cliente:

- PK código cliente
- FK código contato (referência à tabela contato)
- nome cliente

Tabela funcionario:

- PK código funcionário
- FK código contato (referência à tabela contato)
- nome funcionário

Tabela contato:

- PK código contato
- telefone
- e-mail