# Criar um condicional usando o modelo-relacional

Tags: sql, modelo-relacional

Estou tentando criar um condicional "ou" apenas usando o paradigma relacional:

Tendo as tabelas `pessoa`, `cliente`, `funcionario` e considerando que uma pessoa pode ser um cliente ou ser um funcionário (uma relação 1:1, não nula), seria correto referenciar a tabela `cliente` e `funcionario` com a mesma chave estrangeira a partir da tabela `pessoa`? Exemplo:
[image: exemplo]
A chave estrangeira `fk_tipo` referencia `Funcionario.pk_funcionario` e `Cliente.pk_cliente`.
O único problema que encontrei nesse modo é que a tabela `Cliente` não poderá ter uma chave primária igual à outra chave primária da tabela `Funcionario` e vice-versa. Então teria que rever o modo de geração dessas chaves.

Existe alguma outra maneira de realizar o que desejo utilizando ao máximo o modelo relacional?

<sub>Ps.: não é duplicata de "[Uma chave estrangeira pode referenciar mais de uma tabela?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8579/uma-chave-estrangeira-pode-referenciar-mais-de-uma-tabela)".</sub>

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer, poderia dar um exemplo? A propósito, se "todo cliente é uma pessoa" e "todo funcionário é uma pessoa" você pode ter a tabela `pessoa`, normal, e nas tabelas `cliente` e `funcionario` a chave primária ser também chave estrangeira pra tabela `pessoa`. Isso garante a unicidade, mas **não** previne contra: a) a existência de uma pessoa que não é nem cliente nem funcionário; b) a existência de uma pessoa que é tanto cliente quanto funcionário.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, por isso coloquei a chave estrangeira em `pessoa`.

Comment: Nesse caso, qual a diferença entre essa pergunta e a outra linkada? Se você se refere a ter **duas** chaves estrangeiras em `pessoa` - uma pra `cliente` e outra pra `funcionario` - e quer garantir que uma e somente uma delas seja `NULL`, talvez você consiga isso usando [`check`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_constraint) (posso dar uma resposta com exemplo, se for isso mesmo que você procura). Pessoalmente, ainda considero a minha sugestão inicial melhor - de um jeito ou de outro uma das tabelas vai ficar sem integridade referencial, e eu prefiro que seja a base.

Comment: P.S. Segundo o mesmo artigo linkado na Wikipedia, não dá pra usar o `check` para validar **uma única** coluna - garantir que ela seja chave estrangeira pra uma ou outra tabela - pois esse tipo de restrição em geral só valida dados na mesma linha da mesma tabela. E reiterando, não vejo diferença entre essa pergunta e a outra que você diz que "não é duplicata".

Comment: A outra pergunta é sobre se uma chave estrangeira pode referenciar mais de uma tabela, aqui é sobre como seria possível criar um "ou" usando relacional. Acho que ficou um pouco implícito por ter dado ênfase na minha tentativa usando uma chave estrangeira referenciando duas tabelas. Vou tentar dar uma ajustada na pergunta.

Comment: OK, acho que eu entendi agora. Se puder mencionar a **motivação** por trás dessa pergunta (nem que seja "só porque estou curioso pra saber") vai ajudar bastante - pois na prática, não vejo que benefícios isso traria em relação à minha sugestão (que, acabei de ver agora, é a mesma coisa foi sugerido na resposta à pergunta relacionada). De todo modo, +1 pra pergunta, e vou esperar que alguém com mais conhecimento responda (de fato a restrição `check` não cabe aqui).

Comment: A outra pergunta foi realmente por curiosidade, estava tentando descobrir novas formas de como utilizar o modelo relacional. Essa é mais para tentar resolver os problemas por meios simples e não encher o banco de procedures, functions ou triggers.

Comment: Você precisa de ambas tabelas por qual motivo? Ter uma tabela `pessoa` com todos atributos de `funcionario` e `cliente`, e duas colunas para indicar o tipo que a entidade pode assumir (`is_cliente` e `is_funcionario`) resolve a questão da sua aplicação ao meu ver.

Comment: @gmsantos, especificação. Todas as linhas repetidas nas duas tabelas seriam colocadas em `Pessoa`, as restantes em suas devidas tabelas.

Comment: Exatamente isso que sugeri. A diferença é que os atributos exclusivos de cada entidade ficariam nulas dependendo do tipo, e você não precisaria fazer `joins` desnecessários para obter informações de um Funcionário ou Cliente

Comment: Para ficar mais claro: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5afb6d/3

Comment: Sim, até poderia fazer, mas o que almejei ao fazer dessa maneira seria evitar colunas nulas. Além de que isso permitiria uma pessoa ser cliente e funcionário ao mesmo tempo, esse é o motivo do "ou".

Comment: A melhor normalização é o da resposta à pergunta linkada. Não entendi por que ele não resolve todo o problema de relacionamento: você não teria colunas nulas, nem registros repetidos, e uma pessoa poderia ser ou funcionário, ou cliente, ou ambos.

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade, acredito que o ideal seria o contrário. 
Ter nas tabelas: funcionário, cliente uma FK_PESSOA.
Ou seja, todo cliente é uma pessoa. 
Todo funcionário é uma pessoa. 
Uma pessoa pode ser um cliente ou um funcionário.
Ficaria +/- assim, pelo que eu entendi:

```
[pessoa] id, nome, demais campos relativos à pessoa...
[cliente] id, id_pessoa, demais campos relativos a cliente...
[funcionario] id, id_pessoa, demais campos relativos a funcionário...
```

Comment: O problema é que "por acidente", seria possível criar uma pessoa cliente e funcionário ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Realmente... Deste modo precisaria controlar pela aplicação para não ocorrer. Ou até por regras no banco, como trigers, para validar antes de inserir.

Comment: Então é impossível criar um "ou" usando apenas condicional?

Comment: Eu não conheço uma forma de limitar só pelo relacionamento, desta forma.